# Exit button does not exit game

Tags: android, eclipse, exit

When I open my game and click my exit button first, it allows me to end the game. But when I open the game and click my start button, then go back to the form where the EXIT BUTTON is located, it goes back to the previous form. I tried some of the answers here but nothing happens. Help me.

Here is the code

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexit1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?");

        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ad.setCancelable(false);
        ad.setTitle("EXIT CONFIRMATION");
        ad.setMessage("are you sure you want to exit?");
        ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();



            }
        });
        ad.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 dialog.cancel();
            }
        }); 

        ad.show();

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `finish()` do?

Comment: It should end the game but once you clicked another button then clicked exit again, it go back to the previous one. dunno why

Comment: You probably have one `Activity` stacked on another, such that it is going back to the previous `Activity`. So when it is working, you have just the one `Activity` on the stack. When it is not, you have 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should override your OnBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  
}
```